# Javascript Regex replace string with parameter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
Please enter {0}, or {1} and {0}, maybe we have {2} or event {3}.
```

Of course I have an array hold the value with corresponding index like:

```
const values = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

I try to replace all the pattern {number} with many ways, the code below is one of them but it still haven't work:

```
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\b{${i}}\\b`, 'g')
    message.replaceAll(regex, values[i])
  }
```

Expected result:

```
Please enter zero, or one and zero, maybe we have two or event three.
```

Comment: Javascript strings are immutable. Calling `replaceAll` without assignment is useless.

Comment: Also, see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/xy8zkwvo/).

Comment: @ASDFGerte But this is not the only problem why this does not work.

Comment: No, indeed not, but i also never said it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a regex using `const regex = new RegExp(\\b{${i}}\\b, 'g')` will generate a regex like `/\b{0}\b/` and is not a valid expression.

Also, you are not overwriting the value of message, and you do not need a new RegExp to do the replacements.

You can use the counter between the curly braces to get the string to replace using `{${i}}`

```js
let message = "Please enter {0}, or {1} and {0}, maybe we have {2} or event {3}.";
const values = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  message = message.replaceAll(`{${i}}`, values[i])
}
console.log(message);
```

Comment: Awesome, It's work. I used to try this but forget to re assign message!!!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of `.replace()`'s anonymous callback.

```js
// The text
var message = `Please enter {0}, or {1} and {0}, maybe we have {2} or {6} event {3}.`;

// Our replacements, make them global with var
var values = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

// Capture desired content and save the digits into its own capture group
console.log( message.replace( /\{(\d+)\}/g, function(matches, dollar_one){
  
  // If we have a replacement then return it
  if(values[dollar_one]){
    return values[dollar_one];
  }
  // Otherwise return the whole match. {6} from the example above
  else{
    return matches;
  }
}));
```

**Output**

```
Please enter zero, or one and zero, maybe we have two or {6} event three.
```

Comment: thank for your help. The fourth bird's way is what I need and simple for me :)

Comment: @thepnguyennhu No problem. The advantage of my answer is that it has recursion mitigation. Try `values = ['zero', '{3}', 'two', 'three'];` with mine and with theirs to see what I mean.

Comment: yep, to make sure is existed in values

Answer (score 1):

[Similar to @MonkeyZeus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67974868/548225) here is another way to use anonymous replacer in `.replace(/re/, replacer)`:

```js
const message = `Please enter {0}, or {1} and {0}, maybe we have {2} then event {6}/{5} and {3}.`;

// Our replacements
var values = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

// match {digits} and replace with values[index]
var r = message.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, (m, g1) => 
        g1 in values ? values[g1] : m);

console.log(r);
//=> Please enter zero, or one and zero, maybe we have two then event {6}/{5} and three.
```